# How can I write integration tests if I need dynamically generated values from a javscript file?

Tags: c#, integration-tests, .net-core, react

We have a react website that, as part of it's process, loads a dynamically generated javascript file from a third party. It uses some of the scripts in this javascript file to generate values, which the react website then passes to our API in an API call.

Our API then does it's own processing and calls the third party's API, passing back in some of the values generated from their javascript.

These values are only valid for a short time frame.

I'm looking to create some integration tests with the third party's API, but I cannot hard code any values as they are only temporarily valid.

We would only need to perform these integration tests when we modify the client class that calls the third party, so our current solution is to manually set the values but I'm wondering if there is an existing solution to handle this?

Our API is a c# webservice written in .net core.

Comment: Why is manually setting the values insufficient?  You already stated that you would only need to perform these tests when the code changesn and your manually-set values are the moral equivalent of a [stub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_stub).

Answer (score -1):

> our current solution is to manually set the values

Well, then automate that manual process.

From what you wrote, your main program does this already automatically, so I don't see any compelling reason why your tests could not do the same. Ideally, you can reuse the code of your main program in your test. If there are technical reasons which hinders you from doing that, you may be able to mimic the value extraction process somehow. Since you are building an integration test and not a unit test, there should be no restriction on which components to use in your test.